# Get table row count outside scope of table in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008

I can count the rows in the dataset that the table consumes, but this doesn't return the right value as the data in the table is grouped.

I need to know the table size in order to dynamically size a chart that appears along side the table.

CountRows is obviously no good as you have to be in the scope of the table, which I'm not.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about determining the number of rows you'll have this way:
[# of Header Rows] + CountRows("[DataSetName]") + CountDistinct(Fields![group1groupby].Value, "[DataSetName]") + CountDistinct(Fields![group2groupby].Value, "[DataSetName]") ... etc?

Comment: CountDistinct: "The value of scope cannot be an expression and must refer to the current scope or a containing scope."           
I am outside the scope of the original table.

Comment: I just did this in a textbox above a Tablix called "table1" in one of my existing reports which had 4 rows on the header and 3 groupings with header rows below the first two, and it gave me the correct value (the dataset name was "JobCosts"):

=4+(CountDistinct(Fields!Cost_Type.Value, "JobCosts") * 2) + (CountDistinct(iif(Fields!Cost_Type.Value = "Labor", Fields!Cost_Type.Value + CStr(Fields!Op.Value), Fields!Cost_Type.Value + CStr(Fields!Op.Value) + " " + CStr(Fields!Seq.Value)), "JobCosts") * 2) + CountRows("JobCosts")

Are you trying to do this in the header or something?

Comment: No, not in the header, I'll take another look at this and get back to you.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer but will add the caveat that I never got the chance to fully test this out.

Answer (score 4):

Add a hidden column to the tablix, and in the header cell place the expression "=CountRows()".  Being in the header cell means that the count of all rows not the groups counts. You can then reference the header cell (named something like Textbox10) as an expression elsewhere in the report as "=ReportItems!Textbox10.Value".
You could also add a hidden row (not grouped) to the bottom of the tablix, rather than a column, whatever works better for you.  Do this by right clicking on the outermost group and selecting "Insert Row" -> "Outside Group - Below".

Comment: It should be noted that the hidden cell should be outside any groups (such as a header cell), otherwise you'd get the *"Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope."* error.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one tablix add one new row.
2. In last row any one cell write expression like(=CountRows("Tablix1")).That cell Name(Textbox20).
3. Then out side Tablix Insert one textbox(Name is Textbox50)
4. Write expression inside of textbox.. like(=ReportItems!Textbox20.value)
5. That simple its working fine.